# jQuery Mobile site multiple files

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using phonegap and jquery mobile to build an app.
Until now the "all pages in one html file" was being used, but the project is going to be really big and will be bad to have all in one file.
All the pages are in the file index.html
Only one called mentions in mentions.html.

When going from the page "dashboard" from index.html to "mentions" on mentions.html is ok, the transiction go well.
But when the back button is clickd, it goes to the dashboard page with No transiction .

here's my button:

```
 <a href="#dashboard" data-role="button" id="mentions-back-button" class="">Dashboard</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery Mobile's [back button link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html).

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" id="mentions-back-button" class="">Dashboard</a>
```

> "Back" button links If you use the attribute data-rel="back" on an
>   anchor, any clicks on that anchor will mimic the back button, going
>   back one history entry and ignoring the anchor's default href. This is
>   particularly useful when generating "back" buttons with JavaScript,
>   such as a button to close a dialog. When using this feature in your
>   source markup, although browsers that support this feature will not
>   use the specified href attribute, be sure to still provide a
>   meaningful value that actually points to the URL of the referring page
>   to allow the feature to work for users in C-Grade browsers. If users
>   can reach this page from more than one referring pages, specify a
>   sensible href so that the navigation remains logical for all users.
>   Also, please keep in mind that if you just want a reverse transition
>   without actually going back in history, you should use the
>   data-direction="reverse" attribute instead. Note:
>   data-direction="reverse" is meant to simply run the backwards version
>   of the transition that will run on that page change, while
>   data-rel="back" makes the link functionally equivalent to the
>   browser's back button and all the standard back button logic applies.
>   Adding data-direction="reverse" to a link with data-rel="back" will
>   not reverse the reversed page transition and produce the "normal"
>   version of the transition.